# Xcode generates png form pdf with different colors

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf, resources

We are following article to use pdf vector resources in iOS project: http://martiancraft.com/blog/2014/09/vector-images-xcode6/

However we faced problems. If we set color in Photoshop/Illustrator to #039AF0 then exported pdf will generate png with #1185ec color.

[image]

If we use old png way then colors are fine (please ignore pixelized image, the most important is color):

[image]

What can be the cause?

Answer (score 7):

When a new artboard is created in Illustrator it defaults to using Adobe RGB for the color space which doesn't work well with iOS. To make sure the colors remain as close to the original as possible, set the color space to sRGB by selecting "Web" for Profile and RGB for Color Mode under Advanced.

[image: illustrator settings]

This works well for new artboards. I have an Illustrator file as a deliverable that was created in Adobe RGB. For such cases, I've resorted to copy pasting vector paths on a new artboard that's set to sRGB before saving as PDF for use in Xcode 6.

Comment: I wish I could vote you up 1000 times, had weird colours on my pdfs couldn't get it to match. tried everything! this works. thanks!!!!

Comment: Hey. I tried this but it didn't work for me... Any updates or suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem, and finally I found that set the deployment Target to 7.0 or above solves the problem.

Comment: But hot to support iOS 6.0?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that Photoshop/Illustrator generates CMYK or other special colors in the PDF file and Xcode uses the PDF rendering engine that is implemented in iOS to convert the PDF files to PNG.
Because the iOS has problems with displaying CMYK colors, your PNG image has distorted colors.

The above is only an assumption because I have not seen a sample PDF file and the process used by Xcode to convert the PDF to PNG is not documented.

Comment: We tried to add RGB profile to pdf but it didn't help much

Comment: A simple test is to view the PDF file on iPhone/iPad. If the colors are distorted then the PDF file contains special colors. The RGB profile in the PDF file does not help, the colors in the PDF must be specified in RGB (there must be a setting in Illustrator that allows this).

Comment: We tried pdf and it looks perfect on iOS. So the problem is in step that generates pngs

Comment: With more investigation - we see that pdf colors are a little different. So looks like exported pdf use adobe rgb but when you export png it is in srgb