# vector images in xassets have different colors

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, image, ios8

I'm pulling pdf files into Xcode via images.xassets -> image set -> type: vectors.  The PDF looks great, but when I look at the images on the device, the colors are changing slightly.  Exporting the PDF as individual PNG files and doing it the old way is working fine.

Has anyone else run into this? The color change is bad enough to revert back to the old way for any non monochromatic image.  When exporting to PDF with Illustrator, verified that we're using RGB mode and not anything else

Answer (score 0):

check out the deployment target, it should be 7.0 or above. Because of Vector pdf only supports 7.0 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Check Alpha value. I had this issue in the past and the alpha value caused this problem. If i had saved my images with this colours would have been changed a little.

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting on illustrator when exporting to PDF that was causing my problem.  Follow: [Xcode generates png form pdf with different colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26335831/xcode-generates-png-form-pdf-with-different-colors)

Comment: What setting? Was it color profile-related? You’ve solved it, but your solution might be helpful to others with the same issue. And if you add some more detail to answer, you can accept it as the answer to your question.